# Case insensitive imports causing a mess in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm working alongside few people on a project which uses Nextjs v12. Primarily I use windows. Few days earlier I started using Ubuntu via wsl and as soon as I spin up npm run dev I was bombarded with import error which was not case when working in windows. I was using vscode earlier which did all of importing work now I am using neovim. How can I ignore casing errors in imports or is there any work around to correct all case errors

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa3BV.png)

I tired to find any config option but did not find any. It's first time I've faced such issue

Comment: It look's like your using an import alias to import that module. Try checking the ts-config to ensure that the alias is the correct path first. Are the files for this project on your windows hard drive or are they in the linux subsystem's file system?

Comment: @boreddad420 Files are in linux subsystem's file system. I am also having build issues. Thing is I had a dual boot setup earlier and things worked fine

Answer (score -1):

For those who have already worked on Windows for a while, when the project expands to a scale where fixing imports becomes challenging, you can utilize the npm package 'fix-insensitive-import' (refer to this article: https://medium.com/@mohamedjolti/how-to-fix-insensitive-imports-in-javascript-caused-by-fs-like-windows-99edf230a414).
This package systematically examines imports in each file, compares them with the actual file names, and rectifies them one by one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).